# How to prepend div id to div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I add div id of a selected division and prepend it to the division itself?

Here's what I tried:

```js
$(".showID").prepend("<h4>" + $(this).attr("id") + "</h4>");

console.log( $(".trialID").attr("id") ); /*Why does this work?*/
```

```css
div{
  background:royalblue; color:#ddd;
  padding:2rem;margin-bottom:1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foobar" class="showID">
  Hello
  <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div id="loremIpsum" class="showID">
  Hello
  <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div id="helloWorld" class="noID">
  Hello
  <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div id="JonSkeet" class="showID trialID">
  Hello
  <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

When I use `$(".trialID").attr("id");` in browser console it does work...

Is there a way to achieve this with CSS??

Comment: CSS is not programming language, just like HTML, you can only change visuals of element, but not some element attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over all selected `$('.showID')` elements with [jQuery.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```js
$.each($('.showID'), function () {
  $(this).prepend($('<h4>').text($(this).attr('id')))
})
```

```css
div{background:royalblue; color:#ddd;padding:2rem;margin-bottom:1rem;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="foobar" class="showID">
  Hello
  <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div id="loremIpsum" class="showID">
  Hello
  <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div id="helloWorld" class="noID">
  Hello
  <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div id="JonSkeet" class="showID trialID">
  Hello
  <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.
Can't we use your code without the `var`?

$('.showID').each(function (){
    $(this).prepend('<h4>' + $(this).attr('id') + '</h4>');
});

Don't know why but your code scares a noob like me... :(

Is there any upside to your way of coding? Silly question, but I'd like to learn...

Comment: @YourPalNurav yes sure you can do i have updated the anwer.. But the downside is that every time you use `$(this)` jQuery is going to query the DOM and that may affect the performance

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you can do this task using jQuery, but not sure whether you want to do it entirely using CSS.

The problem with your code is that `$(this)` doesn't refer to the current element. You need to loop through the selected `div`s and manually prepend the IDs to those. You can refer to the current element using `$(this)` then.

```js
$(".showID").each(function() {
  $(this).prepend(`<h4>${$(this).attr("id")}</h4>`);
});
```

```css
div {
  background: royalblue;
  color: #ddd;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foobar" class="showID">
  Hello
  <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div id="loremIpsum" class="showID">
  Hello
  <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div id="helloWorld" class="noID">
  Hello
  <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div id="JonSkeet" class="showID trialID">
  Hello
  <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Jquery issue**

So your jquery needs to loop through the class `.showID` or `.trialID`

```js
$(".showID").each(function(){
  $(this).prepend("<h4>" + $(this).attr("id") + "</h4>");
});
```

```css
div{
  background:royalblue; color:#ddd;
  padding:2rem;margin-bottom:1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foobar" class="showID">
  Hello
  <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div id="loremIpsum" class="showID">
  Hello
  <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div id="helloWorld" class="noID">
  Hello
  <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div id="JonSkeet" class="showID trialID">
  Hello
  <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS issue**

Answering the css, there's no way to dynamically get the id attribute. But you can do something like this where it can get the id that starts with specific characters:

```
div[id^="id_"].showID { color: red; }
```

You can add the heading to the divs using JS/jQuery and then decide to show it or not using CSS

See below:

```js
$(".showID").each(function(){
  $(this).prepend("<h4>" + $(this).attr("id") + "</h4>");
});
```

```css
div{
  background:royalblue; color:#ddd;
  padding:2rem;margin-bottom:1rem;
}
div[id^="id_"].showID > h1{ display:block }
div[id^="no_"].showID > h1{ display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id_foobar" class="showID">
  Hello
  <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div id="id_loremIpsum" class="showID">
  Hello
  <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div id="no_helloWorld" class="noID">
  Hello
  <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div id="id_JonSkeet" class="showID trialID">
  Hello
  <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: will `div[id^="id_"].showID{}` work on multiple IDs starting with `id_`?

Comment: Yes just updated the answer with another div with `id_`.

Comment: `div[id^="id_"].showID >h1 { display:block; }
div[id^="no_"].showID > h1 { display:none; }` can something like this be used to hide/show the heading?

Comment: Yes you can do that @YourPalNurav see fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/designtocode/fhgtbyr0/2/